# Induction of modules does not preserve freeness

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

$\newcommand\Mod{\mathrm{Mod}}$Let $f: A \to B$ be a morphism of rings. It induces the induction functor $f_*: \Mod_A \to \Mod_B, M \mapsto M \otimes_A B$. I read [here](http://www.ltcc.ac.uk/media/london-taught-course-centre/documents/LTCC-notes-Lecture4-2019.pdf) that $f_*$ preserves projective modules. Do you have an example that $f_*$ does not preserve free modules? How about free of finite rank? What do I need such that $f_*$ preserves free modules (if not all projectives in $\Mod_B$ are free)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *does* send free modules to free modules.

A free module has the form $M=A^{(\Lambda)}$, a direct sum of copies of $A$. Tensor products preserve direct sums, so
$$
f_*(M)\cong (A\otimes_AB)^{(\Lambda)}\cong B^{(\Lambda)}
$$
is free.

Actually, the simplest way to prove that $f_*$ preserves projective modules is to observe that it preserves direct sums, so free modules go to free modules and summands of free modules then go to summands of free modules.

It can very well happen that not every projective $B$-module is free, but it's irrelevant: such modules need not be “reached” by $f_*$. The simplest example is when $A=k$ is a field and $B$ is a $k$-algebra where not all projective modules are free, for instance $B=M_2(k)$ is the algebra of $2\times2$ matrices over $k$. Every (projective) $A$-module is free, so you can conclude that nonfree projective $B$-modules are not of the form $f_*(M)$.